# how to send picturebox on e-mail using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, picturebox

I want to send picturebox on e-mail using vb.net, but the e-mail is sended empty.

Here is my code

```
 Try
        Dim smtp = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com") ' connexion au serveur SMTP Gmail
        Dim message As New MailMessage
        message.Body = PictureBox1.Container
        message.To.Add(txt_adr.Text) ' choisir l'@ du destinataire
        'message.Body = corp.Text ' le corps du mail a envoyé
        message.From = New MailAddress("*******") ' message from expéditeur
        message.Subject = Objet.Text ' le champs objet du mail
        '------------ connexion avec le SMTP ---------'
        smtp.EnableSsl = True ' activer le chiffremment SSL
        smtp.Port = "587" ' accéder au port de connexion du SMTP
        smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*******", "*********") ' introduire les paramétres de connexion de l'expéditeur
        smtp.Send(message) 'envoyé le mail
        MsgBox("Successful")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "erreur d'envoie")
    End Try
```

then , i try to use a htmlbody , but the image is sended in attachement not a background , and without the text (txt_objet.text)

Here is my html code

```
      Dim img As LinkedResource
        img = New LinkedResource(image_path.Text, "image/jpeg")
        img.ContentId = "myimage"
        Dim htmlbody As String =
           "<html>
            <head>
            <style>
             body {
                   background-image : url(C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\img.jpg); 
                   background-position : center center;
                   }
            </style>
            <body>
            <h1>Picture</h1>
            <br><p>" + txt_objet.Text + "</p>
        </body>
        </html>"
        Dim altview As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlbody, Nothing, "Text/html")
        altview.LinkedResources.Add(img)
        '****** affecter cette format à l'email
        message.AlternateViews.Add(altview)
        message.Body = htmlbody
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Comment: Do you want to send the picture IN the picturebox?

Comment: yes , i want to send a picture in picture box ,in my picturebox ,i have a picture and i put a text on this picture , i want to send it

Comment: Save the picture from the picture box and sent it as attachment of the email

Comment: i send a picture , but without text (text on the picture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First*, save your image in to a file, (if its already available as a file its good)

*Second*, For sending inline images in the email body.
Try the below code:

```
Dim htmlBody As String = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=""cid:filename""></body></html>"
Dim avHtml As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
Dim inline As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource("filename.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline)
Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage
mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml)
Dim att As Attachment = New Attachment(filePath)
att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true
mail.From = New MailAddress("*******")
mail.To.Add(txt_adr.Text)
mail.Subject = Objet.Text
mail.Body = String.Format("<img src=""""cid:{0}"""" />", inline.ContentId)
mail.IsBodyHtml = true
mail.Attachments.Add(att)
```

Comment: but the image is sended without text , i want to send a mail for my freinds , the mail contain background picture and text (on the picture)
but now , the image is sended without text

Comment: You can add your text here `Dim htmlBody As String = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=""cid:filename"">[ADD_TEXT_HERE]</body></html>"` If you want to set image as a background then you need to construct a table and set the background of a td element to this image.

Comment: Change this `background-image : url(C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\img.jpg);` to `background-image:url(cid:myimage);`